# visual studio 2010 memory consumption

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, memory

I am having problems with my visual studio 2010 where its memory consumption increases quickly while the application is open. I unistalled all plug ins and now just have the clean version. But while I have the solution open, the memory increases from ~300K to 1GB to such a point if it hasnt crashed, I need to kill the process. The version of the VS is professional and it happens for different solutions.

I feel it may down to the locking on VS2010 config files eating in to memory but thats a guess.

Anyone have similar issues or how I might go about finding what the issues is?

Comment: Happens for different solutions, or for all solutions? If it's only for some, try unloading some projects on a troublesome solution. If it solves the problem, find which one it was by enabling the projects one by one while working until you see which one exactly is troublesome. Then, I'd look into the references of that project to see if there is a non conventional assembly or something. BUT, I'm just saying, I don't have that issue. (Posted as a comment since it's just an idea, and in no way based on any knowledge.)

Comment: You're not using WinXP by any chance?  I've had many strange problems with VS2010 and large-ish solutions with the older OS.

Answer (score 8):

I was having the exact same problem working with large solutions. Give this plugin a try, [Solution Load Manager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/66350dbe-ed01-4120-bea2-5564eff7b0b2), it lets you essentially "lazy load" projects in your solution, so you only have the ones you're actively working in open and consuming memory.

Worked wonders for me.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tipx.  Never seen such an issue.  My studio hovers around 300MB, but the solution I have open right now has 10 class libraries and 11 web application projects in it.

I'd say open visual studio, start a brand new blank .net solution and let it sit.  If it's memory jumps to 1GB, then do a complete uninstall ( http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall ) and reinstall it from the ground up.  If it continues exhibiting the behavior on a blank solution then I'd suggest wiping the OS from the machine because something else is really wrong.

If it's memory doesn't climb, then create a blank solution and slowly add your projects into it until something happens.  Fix the project showing the behavior.

Of course, if you have a large number of projects OR some third party code is executing on them then 1GB of RAM might be exactly what it needs.  I know Telerik's stuff will inspect each project as you click on it to determine if it has the latest version of the controls...  I'm guessing others will do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new directory
2. Move project files new directory (without *sln* and *sou* files)
3. Open project from new location

that's all.

Comment: I think what you're suggesting is equivalent to this:  do a complete clean of all projects in the solution (if you use TFS, then do `tfpt scorch`).  Of course a last ditch effort is to redo the .sln file from scratch.